# Changing object value globaly

Tags: arrays, swift, list

I want to change a value in object itself, like

```
obj.var = newValue
```

But when getting this locally like in

```
for item in myArray.filter( ... ) {
    item.var = newValue
}
```

this only effects the local copy in the for loop. I can do it using the index within the original array like

```
index = myArray.index(of: item) 
myArray[index].var = newValue
```

But this looks so strange and not very elegant and not performant to me. Is there a more simple solution, easier to read (and write), maybe a general solution for all lists/arrays? How do you handle this common task?

(I'm using Swift 3.0)

Comment: Your first line of code suggests that you want to update a **specific** var (or maybe a **specific array index** var, but your next code snippet (the for..in loop) suggests your wish to update **all array** vars. Which is it? If it's the latter, consider using **for i in 0..<array.cout** as your loop definition.

Comment: the loop is an example. I want to change the value of the object, not the local version in "item", but also (additionaly) in myArray. So when I run a loop on myArray again, the updated values are there. But this could also happen in filtered subsets, so index used within the loop is not the same needed for global array (myArray)

Comment: Show `obj` declaration to find out what it is (class, struct...).

Comment: It is defined as a class.

Answer (score 2):

I think your var is value type not a class. So if you make it a class. That will do what you want to do